# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown Menu offset with strange graphic

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Twitter Bootstrap Navbar and all is working well except that the dropdown menus are offset by 40 pixels and have a strange shadowed graphic to the left of the drop down.

I've inspected it to figure out what it might be, have attempted to reset radius, margin and padding but all to no avail.

If I knew what it was, that would be a great help.

[image: Original Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown]

[image: With box-shadow removed]

**Update**

Thanks Christian Varga, the strange shape was indeed box-shadow and I've removed that.  I am just left with the left margin of what looks like 40 pixels wrapping the whole drop down list.

I have posted the HTML and CSS below

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href=@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Area = ""}) class="navbar-brand"><img id="alogo" src="~/Content/images/logos/logo.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <nav class="nav navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href=@Url.Action("Index", "Controller", new { Area = "AreaName"})><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-2x"></i><br />Top Level</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href=@Url.Action("Index", "Controller", new { Area = "AreaName"})>Drop Down 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=@Url.Action("Details", "Controller", new { Area = "AreaName" })>Drop Down 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    /*Nav Bar Styling*/

    .nav {
        background-color: #3B5998;
        width: auto;
    }

    .navbar-inverse {
        background-color: #3B5998;
        border-color: #E7E7E7;
    }
        .nav ul; {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

            .nav ul li {
                list-style: none;
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 0;
            }

                .nav ul li a {
                    display: block;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    text-align: center;
                    /*left upper right bottom*/
                    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                    transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
                    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s; /* Safari */
                }

                .nav ul li:hover a {
                    color: #efefef;
                    padding-bottom: 10px;
                    background-color: #293E6A;
                    transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
                    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s; /* Safari */
                }

                /* Drop Down */

                .nav ul li ul {
                    display: none;
                }

                .nav ul li:hover ul {
                    z-index: 2;
                    position: absolute;
                    display: block;
                }

                .nav ul li ul {
                    position: relative;
                    /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
                    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;*/
                }

                    .nav ul li ul:before, .nav ul li ul:after {
                        content: "";
                        position: absolute;
                        z-index: -1;
                        /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
                        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
                        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);*/
                        top: 50%;
                        bottom: 0;
                        left: 10px;
                        right: 10px;
                        -moz-border-radius: 100px / 10px;
                        border-radius: 100px / 10px;
                    }

                    .nav ul li ul li {
                        list-style: none;
                        display: block;
                        float: none;
                    }

                        .nav ul li ul li:hover a {
                            color: #293E6A;
                            padding-bottom: 10px;
                            background-color: #efefef;
                            transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
                            -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s; /* Safari */
                        }

                    .nav ul li ul li {
                    }

                        .nav ul li ul li a {
                            padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
                            text-align: left;
                        }

                            .nav ul li ul li a i {
                                min-width: 20px;
                                padding-right: 10px;
                            }

        /* Drop Down Arrow */

        .nav li > a:after {
            content: ' »';
        }


        .nav > li > a:after {
            content: ' »';
        }


        .nav li > a:only-child:after {
            content: '';
        }

        /* Active Class */

        .nav ul .active {
            color: #FFF;
        }

        .navbar-brand {
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;    
        }

</style>
```

Comment: That looks more like a `box-shadow` on whatever is wrapping the entire sub-menu, and then a `margin-left` on the individual sub-menu items. But without seeing code, it's virtually impossible to tell.

Comment: If we could see your code and a working example of the problem that would be a great help.